# React controlled select element reverts to first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, html-select

I am using React to create a controlled select element. My app validates the new option value selected by the user and then updates that value on the element.
The validation takes some time and the behavior I observe is as follows:

- User selects an option
- Element changes the selected option to index 0
- Once the validation period is over, the element updates itself to the new value

I do not understand why the element reverts to the first index and how can I prevent this (except by setting the value immediately which is undesired in my application)

Use this JSFiddle to see this behavior (select Option2)   https://jsfiddle.net/qo39g2j4/

```
var Select = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <select id="my-select" value={this.props.value} onChange={this.props.onChange}>
            <option value="Option1">Option1</option>
            <option value="Option2">Option2</option>
            <option value="Option3">Option3</option>
        </select>
    );
  }
});

var Wrapper = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {value: "Option3"};
    },
    onChange: function (event) {
        var value = event.target.value;
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.setState({value: value});
        }.bind(this), 1000); // this simulates the validation period
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
            <Select
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.onChange}/>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <Wrapper/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `defaultValue` instead of `value` in your `Select` component. Or add `event.preventDefault()` in `onChange`.

Comment: Changing value to defaultValue would make this an uncontrolled component preventing me from changing its value if the validation fails. event.preventDefault() doesn't seem to work in the JSFiddle and the real app

Comment: @AmitFridman maybe you can try setting the `state` twice `onChange`. before the validation, and after the validation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when integrating [redux-form](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-form) within my app, due to an issue in onBlur event handler,
so here is how i handled it using customSelect react component :

```
export default class CustomSelect extends Component {
  render() {
    const { children, value, onBlur, ...props } = this.props

    return (
      <select
        {...props}
        onBlur={() => onBlur(value)}
      >
      {children}
      </select>
    )
  }
}
```

Here onBlur eventHandler is explicitly called with the value passed, to keep it selected

Also validation on client-side or server-side should not be represented by a timeout as user is expected to see the wrong input data with the validation message if invalid,

I guess your implementation means that selected option would be visible only if valid which is not the best user experience you can have, if that's the actual case

Solution is based on [redux-form react-select bug](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/82)